# Extending existing cordova plugins / phonegap modules

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0, javascript

I've spent a lot of time trying to extend an existing cordova plugin, but didn't manage so far and need your guidance:

I want to use phonegap (cordova 2.1) to record audio on android and ios.
The default setting works, but I need to be able to configure record-settings in my app. The user must be able to pick BitEncodingRate, SamplingRate etc.

These settings are currently hardcoded in the Cordova Media Plugin. (to be exact - in the AudioPlayer class for android).
I'd like to reuse as much as possible from the functions that are already there and simply add the function.

```
Media.startRecordWithSettings(settings)
```

But it's not clear to me how to tackle this problem.

Is it not possible to extend the cordova Media plugin like this:

```
Media.prototype.startRecordWithSettings = function() {
    exec(null, this.errorCallback, "MyMedia", "startRecordWithSettings", [this.id, this.src]);
};
```

Because I do not want to manipulate the cordova.js file, which implements the Media plugin as JS-module. 
My current idea is to duplicate all code that is needed for the phonegap Media plugin. (I would duplicate the part of cordova.js that defines the Media object, add the lines above, and also duplicate the Java classes that are needed on OS-Side and wrap them into a Plugin that looks the same as the existing cordova plugin, but with record settings).

As you can see I am desperate. Instead of extending a module and adding the custom function that I need and reusing exiting code, I am about to duplicate everything.

Ok I could also edit the cordova.js and Cordova Java classes to fit my needs, but then I could never update to the newest cordova version, because I would overwrite my "fixes".

Is it possible to extend cordova plugins at all? Or must I rewrite them, if they don't fit my needs?

I found [this plugin](https://github.com/lylepratt/phonegap-plugins/commit/6acef31e51ed5837d06c9078d9047dc560b36b41) for iOS, but it seems like a lot has changed since this plugin was implemented, because if I write something like this in my custom javascript part:

```
    Media.prototype.startRecordWithSettings = function() { ... }
```

The logs say: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined at ..."

I am new to the [JavaScript module pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247241/Javascript-Module-Pattern) and I don't understand how I could extend a phonegap JS-module.

Please help me.

Comment: I try to simplify my question: cordova.js contains many js-modules that are connected to cordova plugins. What would you do if you wanted to add an extra function to a specific modul and plugin? Would you change cordova.js and the source classes directly? Would you duplicate the things you need and wrap it in an own plugin? (extending a CordovaPlugin in java is also not possible, because some instance variables you need are package protected)

Comment: sorry i mean package private. E.g. AudioHandler.java has a List of AudioPlayers that are invisible for subclasses.